# Is there any way/platform on which SQL binds can be evaluated as-needed, during query execution?

Tags: sql, bind, sql-execution-plan, ondemand

**Context:**

Say I have a large query (pseudo):

```
SELECT %boundthing,data
WHERE data in (
    ...do lots of long-running stuff
)
```

Let's assume `boundthing` isn't being used in my query anywhere but when I want to print the output (I know it's a stupid use case, but it illustrates the point that I know `boundthing` won't be needed until after the `WHERE` clause runs).

As it is, if I pass the value for `boundthing` to my query in the programming language of my choice, it's evaluated when I fire the query off, regardless of how much later on it will actually be "used" by the database.

**Question:**

Is there a way (in an existing database/programming language) to set a bind-style thing to be evaluated (that is, it produces a value for the bound variable, whether the source is a variable or a function) on-demand in a query, rather than when the query plan is built?

For example, I could say, in application pseudocode:

```
function MyFunc:
    return "foo" + system.GetEpochTimestamp();

var results = database_handle.Execute( SQL = "
    SELECT %boundthing,data
    WHERE data in (
        ...do lots of long-running stuff
    )", BINDS = [ ("boundthing", MyFunc ) ]
);
```

And the value of "boundthing" in the output would correspond to the timestamp *on the application server, after the* `WHERE` *clause filtered everything* (minus the runtime of `myfunc` on the application server, and however long it took for the data to make it to the database server and be processed by the database).

**Why I want to know:**

Curiosity.

I know that something like this would probably destroy a lot (maybe all) of the efficiency lent by a query planner. I know that you would never have a guarantee that the evaluation of the bind would be executed *exactly when* the value was needed in the query (there's value transmission time, processing time on the database, etc). I also know that it violates a lot of atomicity guarantees and could cause serious problems in the event of an abort or outage.

Still, I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC MyFunc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM data where data in ( ...do lots of long-running stuff);
    $boundthing='EXEC boundthing'
    select $boundthing, * from #MyTempTable
END
GO
```

Comment: This is kind of scary, from an arbitrary-code-execution point of view, but works in a pinch, I guess. Maybe someday there will be a database driver that allows clients to specify (or hint at) bind evaluation techniques.